# Quero o índice de uma célula, dado os números da coluna e da linha

Tags: matemática

Eu estava tendo uns problemas com array2D no c# então eu decidi tentar usar uma array normal

[image: (exemplo)]

Suponhamos que eu tenha a coluna 4 (vermelho) e a linha 3 (azul), qual é a fórmula para eu conseguir o número que corresponde a elas (22, verde)?

Comment: Qual é a dúvida? Onde está o código? Deveria resolver o problema que tem na ferramenta correta para o problema, tentar fazer gambiarra faz você ter 2 ou mais problemas agora.

Comment: @Maniero, creio eu que ele precisa dum código que localize o índice do número na tabela usando linha e coluna.

Comment: Usar um array normal quando a informação que tem é 2d so lhe cria mais problemas. Resolva os problemas que tinha no array2d e use esse que é o mais apropriado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No caso da primeira linha, primeira coluna e primeira célula puderem ter valores arbitrários (não necessariamente 0 ou 1 e possivelmente diferentes entre si), a fórmula geral para achar-se o número da célula com base no número da linha e no número da coluna é essa:

```
celula = (linha - primeira_linha) * largura + (coluna - primeira_coluna) + primeira_celula
```

As fórmulas inversas, para achar-se os números da linha e da coluna a partir do número da célula são essas:

```
linha = (celula - primeira_celula) / largura + primeira_linha
coluna = (celula - primeira_celula) % largura + primeira_linha
```

No caso, os valores `primeira_linha`, `primeira_coluna` e `primeira_celula` são, como os nomes indicam, o número dado à primeira linha da matriz (pode ser 1, 0, ou qualquer outro valor), o número dado à primeira coluna da matriz e o número dado a cada célula individual. No seu caso, específico, essas três variáveis têm todas elas o valor 1, e portanto essas fórmulas ficam assim:

```
celula = (linha - 1) * largura + (coluna - 1) + 1

linha = (celula - 1) / largura + 1
coluna = (celula - 1) % largura + 1
```

No entanto, como no C# os arrays são indexados com o primeiro elemento tendo índice 0, normalmente faz sentido que essa três variáveis tenham o valor 0, tornando as fórmulas nisso:

```
celula = linha * largura + coluna

linha = celula / largura
coluna = celula % largura
```

Observe que a fórmula quando as variáveis `primeira_linha`, `primeira_coluna` e `primeira_celula` são zero é razoavelmente mais simples. Isso ocorre porque a finalidade dessas variáveis na fórmula é exatamente a de converter os índices arbitrários da primeira linha, primeira coluna e primeira célula para o equivalente de quando todos eles forem zeros.

No formato baseado no 0, cada linha corresponde a um bloco de células. O tamanho desse bloco é a largura da matriz. Dentro do bloco correspondente, desloca-se um número de células igual ao das colunas. Por isso que para encontrar a célula a partir das linhas e das colunas que o valor da largura é multiplicado pela linha e o valor da coluna é somado.